# Standardize by group using data.table

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

Is it possible to use data.table to standardize a number of variables by a number of group variables?

```
DT <- data.table(V1=1:20, V2=40:21, gr=c(rep(c('a'),10), rep(c('b'),10)),
             grr=rep(c(rep(c('a'),5), rep(c('b'),5)),2))
```

gr and grr are the group variables. I want to add to that data.table V1.z and V2.z that are the standardized score within each gr-by-grr group.

Here is an extremely stupid code for that, to explain what I want:

```
DTaa <- DT[gr=='a' & grr=='a',]
DTab <- DT[gr=='a' & grr=='b',]
DTba <- DT[gr=='b' & grr=='a',]
DTbb <- DT[gr=='b' & grr=='b',]
DTaa <- DTaa[,V1.z := scale(V1)]
DTaa <- DTaa[,V2.z := scale(V2)]
DTab <- DTab[,V1.z := scale(V1)]
DTab <- DTab[,V2.z := scale(V2)]
DTba <- DTba[,V1.z := scale(V1)]
DTba <- DTba[,V2.z := scale(V2)]
DTbb <- DTbb[,V1.z := scale(V1)]
DTbb <- DTbb[,V2.z := scale(V2)]
DTn <- rbind(DTaa, DTab, DTba, DTbb)
```

Probably, there is a way to do it using `by` in one or two lines.

- I'm hoping to then use it in a function that accepts data, the target variables (in the example, V1 and V2), and group variables (in the example, gr and grr) as arguments.
- If you have a solution that does not use data.table, it's also good (I tried using mutate_at from dplyr but couldn't find much documentation about that function).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After grouping by 'gr' and 'grr', loop over the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`), `scale` it (the output of `scale` is a `matrix`, so we convert it to `vector` with `as.vector`) and assign (`:=`) the output to the new columns.

```
DT[, paste0(names(DT)[1:2], ".z") := lapply(.SD, 
                  function(x) as.vector(scale(x))), .(gr, grr)]
```

Comment: Amazing. Thanks. 
A follow-up question: 

I added V3 and V4 to the data.table and your code still knew to convert only the first two variables. That's good, but how did it work? I mean, how does data.table know we want the action to be performed only on the first and second column? The only thing I see here is in paste0, but that's just for the names of the new variables. What if I want to use the name from columns 1 and 2 and perform the action on columns 3 and 4 (if I had those columns)?

Comment: @YBA In general, the `.SD` includes all the columns that are not specified in the `by` columns i.e. `(gr, grr)`.  Suppose, you have some other columns and you want  only to do on 'V1' and 'V2', specify those in `.SDcols` i.e. `.SDcols = V1:V2` and then loop through the `.SD` as showed in the post.

Comment: The .SDcols is very useful, thanks. 

So, I have an idea why your code still worked after adding V3 and V4: it seems that if you specify only two names for the new columns, the function will be performed only on the first two columns (that are not in the 'by' statement).

Comment: @YBA Yes, you need to specify it in `.SDcols`